# setting up a local CICD setup

Tags: git, jenkins, server, ubuntu-12.04, devops

I have two local server that is connected in local network in my office, This is integrated in VM vSphere. I Would like to integrate CICD in my office. I Created two servers one is Git server and another one is jenkins server. Two servers are working fine also. But am not getting how to integrate this git servers one repository in the jenkins server. our office we are using only php applications. Below are the  problems that i facing now

1. How to integrate git server's repository in jenkins server.
2. how to integrate this git servers repository in git client (ubuntu+windows)

please advice me to achieve this

jenkins and git-servers are installed in ubuntu 12.04 server

Answer (score 1):

> How to integrate git server's repository in jenkins server.

Use the [JENKINS/Git+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin): that will allow any job to reference the Git repo URL, in order for said job to get back the repo sources in the Jenkins slave build workspace.

> how to integrate this git servers repository in git client (ubuntu+windows)

All a git client needs to do is to use the Git server repo URL in order to clone/pull/push. Depending on the nature of the server, you might have to deal with authentication/authorization.